# Powershell Form Layout

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

How do I control the layout of this form so that my group boxes align vertically?

Say I create a form like this:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$groupBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox1.text = "Group Box 1"

$groupBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox2.text = "Group Box 2"

$form.controls.add($groupBox1)
$form.controls.add($groupBox2)

$form.showdialog()
```

Doing this only shows my `$groupBox1` group box.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either set position for each groupbox or use some kind of table layout:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$groupBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox1.text = "Group Box 1"

$groupBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox2.text = "Group Box 2"

$tableLayoutPanel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2

$tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add($groupBox1, 0, 0);
$tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add($groupBox2, 0, 1);
$tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
$form.controls.add($tableLayoutPanel1)

$form.showdialog()
```

Comment: There are multiple Panels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx It looks like FlowLayoutPanel and SplitterPanel are the other two types that could be used to answer this question, though there are other types of Panels.

Comment: On FlowLayoutPanel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control